# vs code ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use python on Windos in vs code.
I'm currently struggling with importing a package.

I have installed the package with pip, and it shows me that it is installed:
[image]

But when I try to import the modul I get the message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Twitter'"

[image]

I found that it is possible to add the libary path trough the launch.json file. I added the line: "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/Lib/site-packages"}
But it is still not working.

What am I missing?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/twitter/ says that you should `import twitter` or `from twitter import Twitter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please distinguish **t** from **T**. Python statements **twitter** and **Twitter** point to different content respectively.

Use the following command to import:

```
import twitter
```

[image]